# Flash: resize text box without transform

Tags: flash

When I create a static text box (text field), and want to resize it to a specific width, how do I do this? When using the size properties, it transforms the text (wrong aspect ratio). When using the handles on the box (in typing mode), you have no control over the exact width.

I am working in the IDE of Flash 8.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to change it later it should be dynamic.If you want to animate it put it in movieclip and animate movieclip. And for the sake of spagetti monster use some current applications.

Comment: Changing it later is not relevant in my case. I could also have asked: how do you create a static textbox with width (let's say) 100px?

Comment: Besides I know Flash 8 is not a current application, but it would be more helpful if someone could explain it can be done (easier) in later versions.

Comment: Properties panel have options for that. Can you see it?

Comment: If I change the width in the properties panel, the text gets transformed (wrong aspect ratio).

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you. I can't try and see.